# textfield verify method obj c

Tags: objective-c, numbers, uitextfield

I have a view with 2 textfields fields and a button.

in the "clickOnDoneButton" function I have to perform the following function: I have to verify that the pin inserted in the first textfield with the second textfield.
I have to verify the pin with the "checkValidityPin" function which is correct, I cannot implement it correctly.
the logic to be implemented is: I check the first "pin" entered with checkValidityPin, if it is correct I check it with the second "pin" which must be the same.

I think I got lost in the function I can no longer go on ..

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *confirmButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet InputTextView *insertPin;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet InputTextView *verifyPin;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* stringInserted;

- (IBAction) clickOnDoneButton:(id)sender;


- (IBAction) clickOnDoneButton:(id)sender{
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSString * errorMessage = @"";

            if(!self.insertPin || [self.insertPin isEqual:[NSString string]]) {
                self.insertPin = self.stringInserted;
//                [self.insertPin redrawWithInputLength:0];
    //            self.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"INSERT_NEW_PIN", nil);
//                [self setTextAnimated:NSLocalizedString(@"INSERT_NEW_PIN", nil)];
//                self.keyboard.confirButton.enabled = NO;
                self.stringInserted = [NSString string];
            } else if(!self.verifyPin || [self.verifyPin isEqual:[NSString string]]) {
                if (![self.stringInserted isEqualToString:self.insertPin]){
                    if([self checkValidityPin:self.stringInserted]){
                        self.verifyPin = _stringInserted;

//                        [self.fieldView redrawWithInputLength:0];
    //                    self.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"REINSERT_NEW_PIN", nil);
//                        [self setTextAnimated:NSLocalizedString(@"REINSERT_NEW_PIN", nil)];
//                        self.keyboard.confirButton.enabled = NO;
                        self.stringInserted = [NSString string];
                        NSLog(@"TEST4");
                    }
                    else{
                        errorMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"WRONG_PIN_FORMAT", nil);
                        NSLog(@"TEST2");

                    }
                } else {
                    errorMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"NEW_PIN_EQUALS_OLD", nil);
                    NSLog(@"TEST3");

                }
            }

            else if([self.verifyPin isEqual:self.stringInserted]) {
                NSLog(@"TEST");
            }
            else {
//                [self.fieldView redrawWithInputLength:0];
                self.stringInserted = [NSString string];
                self.insertPin = nil;
                self.verifyPin = nil;
                NSLog(@"TEST1");

//                [self setTextAnimated:NSLocalizedString(@"INSERT_OLD_PIN", nil)];
                //            self.keyboard.confirButton.enabled = NO;
                errorMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"PIN_NOT_EQUALS", nil);
            }

            //Show Error
//            if([errorMessage length]>0){
//                [self showError:errorMessage];
//            }

        }];
}

-(BOOL) checkValidityPin:(NSString*)pin{
    NSString *regex1 = @"^(01234|12345|23456|34567|45678|56789)$";
    NSString *regex2 = @"^(98765|87654|76543|65432|54321|43210)$";
    NSString *regex3 = @"^([0-9])\\1*$";

    BOOL testPassed1 = [PRUtility validateRegularExpression:regex1 forString:pin];
    BOOL testPassed2 = [PRUtility validateRegularExpression:regex2 forString:pin];
    BOOL testPassed3 = [PRUtility validateRegularExpression:regex3 forString:pin];

    return !(testPassed1 || testPassed2 || testPassed3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to get lost if you're only writing code. Try writing it in "plain language" first, and then fill in the code.

For example:

1. get each entered string
2. is the entered pin empty? If so, inform the user (update the UI) and don't bother with any other checking.
3. are both entered strings the same? If not, inform the user (update the UI) and don't bother with any other checking.
4. strings are the same, so validate the entered pin
5. is the pin in a valid format? If not, inform the user (update the UI) and don't bother with anything else.
6. pins match and have been validated, so continue with your next step

Here it is with the code filled in:

```
- (IBAction)clickOnDoneButton:(id)sender {

    // 1. get each entered string
    NSString *insertPinString = [_insertPin text];
    NSString *verifyPinString = [_verifyPin text];

    // 2. is the entered pin empty?
    if ([insertPinString length] == 0) {
        // inform user he didn't enter a pin
        // update error label or show alert, whatever

        NSLog(@"No Pin Entered");

        // don't bother with anything else
        return;
    }

    // 3. are both entered strings the same?
    if (![insertPinString isEqualToString:verifyPinString]) {
        // inform user the pins don't match
        // update error label or show alert, whatever

        // probably clear both fields
        _insertPin.text = _verifyPin.text = @"";

        NSLog(@"Pin Mismatch");

        // don't bother with anything else
        return;
    }

    // 4. strings are the same, so validate entered pin
    BOOL bValid = [self checkValidityPin:insertPinString];

    // 5. if invalid pin entered
    if (!bValid) {
        // inform user it's an invalid pin format
        // update error label or show alert, whatever

        // probably clear both fields
        _insertPin.text = _verifyPin.text = @"";

        NSLog(@"Invalid Pin");

        // don't bother with anything else
        return;
    }

    // 6. pins match and have been validated so we can proceed with next step
    NSLog(@"Successful pin entry!");

}
```